# Getting return value from Activity Dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialog

Found so many similar questions here, bt what differs is that everyone else is using DialogFragment. I am using an Activity as Dialog using `Theme.Dialog` in android manifest and `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the `onCreate()` method of the dialog activity. My activity has a EditText and A button. On click of button, I wan't EditText value to be returned to the parent activity and a status change alert or something to trigger something in parent activity. But I am unable to find any reverse pipeline from dialog activity to parent activity. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can startActivityForResult() you "dialog". And set result when it done.
Additional info: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html
Regards Dzmitry.